# Vue Javascript forEach loop inside method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm trying to add multiple images and i can't find a way to make it work.

I have this method:

```
        imageAdd(e) {         
            e.forEach(function(e) {
            if (e.type == 'image/jpeg' || e.type == 'image/png')
            {
                this.images.push({
                    image: URL.createObjectURL(e),
                    imageData: e
                    })
            }
            })
   },
```

When i try to push to images array, it brings me this error `Cannot read property 'images' of undefined` although it is defined inside my data. What's the problem here?

Comment: `.forEach(/*...*/, this)` or `.forEach(/*...*/.bind(this)` or related.

Comment: @ASDFGerte or an arrow function, I guess.

Comment: True, or use `for ... of` instead of `.forEach`, which is often superior anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function instead a usual one that has its own `this`:

```js
 imageAdd(e) {         
            e.forEach((e) => {
            if (e.type == 'image/jpeg' || e.type == 'image/png')
            {
                this.images.push({
                    image: URL.createObjectURL(e),
                    imageData: e
                    })
            }
            })
   }
```

Comment: Yep, made it work like a charm. I used a for statement but this one looks more clean to me.